# patch and run "collides with existing file" error unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I can't patch and run in Unity to my samsung galaxy A70 android phone. I get the error:

> The destination path `<path>` collides with existing foler. Please delete `<same path>` before retrying the operation.

It only happens in a specific project. The only thing I really found about it only were invalid characters in the project name, all of which I removed, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Unity doesnt run on your phone. A game you have made does.  I believe this falls outside the scope for SO

Comment: Try to find a concrete question with enough detail first, then you or somebody else might be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Unity regression, e.g. per [Unity's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/mac-android-file-build-and-run-fails-with-a-prompt). Best, update your Unity version, for example, to one of the following or above.

> Fixed in 2020.3.48f1, 2021.3.25f1, 2022.2.18f1, 2023.1.0b15, 2023.2.0a13

Answer (score 0):

Building once to PC seemed to "fix" it. Afterwards patching would work. Yet, I cannot provide any further understanding to this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

1. Create ‘Editor’ folder in Assets.
2. Create new script inside and name it ‘Build255.cs’.
3. Open script then add this code in.

---

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using System.IO;

public class Build255 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [MenuItem("Build/Build %b")]
    public static void MyBuild()
    {
        BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        //** Custom Open Window Panel to Get locationPath and productName
        //BuildPlayerWindow.DefaultBuildMethods.GetBuildPlayerOptions(buildPlayerOptions);

        string path = Path.Join(buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName, Application.productName);
        if (File.Exists(path + "_BurstDebugInformation_DoNotShip"))
            File.Delete(path + "_BurstDebugInformation_DoNotShip");
        if (File.Exists(path+".apk"))
            File.Delete(path+".apk");

        buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = path+".apk";
        //** Custom BuildTarget (Android, ios, Windows, Linux ,... )
        buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.Android;
        buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;
        buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.AutoRunPlayer;
        BuildReport report = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
        BuildSummary summary = report.summary;

        if (summary.result == BuildResult.Succeeded)
            Debug.Log("Build succeeded: " + summary.totalSize + " bytes");

        if (summary.result == BuildResult.Failed)
            Debug.Log("Build failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).